# Line plot for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataframe looks like the image below

[image: Dataframe]

It wanted to plot a line plot for each month. i tried plotting the line graph following some tutorial

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

but i got the graph like this

[image: Graph]

isn't it supposed to have a line for each month. I cannot understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: Your data goes up and down to frequently so the last line (`dec`) covers all the other lines.

Comment: @QuangHoang but the x axis is supposed to be the range of the values in each month isn't it? but it is showing there in y axis.

Comment: No, the `x` axis is your index, running from `0` to `999998`.

Comment: @QuangHoang can we interchange them? index on y axis and values range  on x axis